how to read each value from JSON array in Groovy
I am new to Groovy and trying to read each value from a JSON array.
logic I wanted to achieve through the loop.
Input JSON
{
    "AUnit": "EA",
    "Quantity": 2,
      
    "SerialNumbers": [
        {
            "SNumber": "IR-240607000100"
        },
        {
            "SNumber": "IR-240607000101"
        }
    ]
}
   
**Groovy Code which I tried with loop :**

     def Message processData(Message message) {
            //Get message and parse to json
            
            def json = message.getBody(java.io.Reader) 
            def data = new JsonSlurper().parse(json)
        
            data.SerialNumbers.each { element ->
                    // Get SerialNumber
                    def sourceValue_Number="${record.text()}"
               def builder_AddSrlNmbr = new JsonBuilder();
                builder_AddSrlNmbr
                {
                    'SerialNumber'  sourceValue_SerialNumber
                    
                
                } 
    }
        return message
     }

logic I wanted to achieve through the loop.
Output expected
{
            "SNumber": "IR-240607000100"
  }
            
{
            "SNumber": "IR-240607000101"
 }

Thank you
Sateesh

You are removing the outer container, but you always have to return a container. You can convert this to JSONND later.  So your Message has to deal with this or the consumer of Message.  Or this question lacks an essential tag.

So getting it working without all the Message/body stuff you have going on, we can create a String with your example input:
String body = '''{
    "AUnit": "EA",
    "Quantity": 2,
      
    "SerialNumbers": [
        {
            "SNumber": "IR-240607000100"
        },
        {
            "SNumber": "IR-240607000101"
        }
    ]
}'''

We can then parse this json into a variable
import groovy.json.*

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body)

And then for each entry in the SerialNumbers list, we can create a new object containing the value with the required key:
def newBody = json.SerialNumbers.collect {
    [SerialNumber: it.SNumber]
}

And then use JsonBuilder to change this back into a pretty string
String result = new JsonBuilder(newBody).toPrettyString()

If we print result out, we can see it's the required result:
[
    {
        "SerialNumber": "IR-240607000100"
    },
    {
        "SerialNumber": "IR-240607000101"
    }
]


Hello Tim,
Thank you for your kind support.
I am looking for output to be print individually (ex: first value appears in the first loop exectuation)  and second value appears in the second loop execution, it means
I want to read the value indivisually

json.SerialNumbers.each{ println it.SNumber }

It gives same result again

I don't understand what the problem is, or what you want as a solution

@Sateesh, you can change loop to java style if it's looks better for you: for(it in json.SerialNumbers) { println it.SNumber }

or for(int i=0; i<json.SerialNumbers.size(); i++){ println json.SerialNumbers[i].SNumber }
